# define bigrand function in java

Tags: algorithm

here is code of bigrand function in c code

```
int bigrand (){
 return  RAND_MAX* rand()+rand();
}
```

please tell me what is equivalent    code in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`java.util.Random`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is the Java SE random generator, with subclasses e.g. [`java.security.SecureRandom`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) for a more cryptographically stronger generator.

#### API links

- [`int nextInt(int n)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

  - Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)
- [`double nextDouble()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29)

  - Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed double value between 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: random function i know but more deeply code which i have  wrote how can i translate in java?

Comment: See the nextLong documentation on the same page, you'll want something similar depending on how big RAND_MAX was originally.